# 12v capacitor / UPS system

Tags: automotive, 12v, ups

I am looking to make a capacitor/UPS system for a few different electrical components in my car. I want to power the rear view camera, headrest monitors, and possibly the head unit for about 30 seconds after their individual power has been isolated. That way they will all stay on when the power supply is changed, for example when the car is turned over. Not sure where to start or anything really about capacitors. I can get the current draw for all the components, but dont know what Diode/Capacitors to buy and wire in.

Comment: While that doesn't sound like a duplicate that answers the main part of the question of sizing the capacitors. So first step is to work that out, diodes that will be able to handle it are cheap and more info would be needed to give an answer on how to connect them.

Answer (score 1):

If you can reduce your requirement to the situation of the car engine being started and the battery voltage being significantly lower than 12 volts then try using a boost regulator set to produce 15 volts followed by a 12 volt linear regulator to exclusively power the cameras.

It will probably be cheaper, smaller and more reliable than using a large bank of capacitors. This sepic controller will possibly do the job just as easily: -

[image]

It works down to an input voltage of 5V (this may be ok during turning the starter motors) and directly produces 12V without a linear regulator. Is 1A sufficient for the camera system?

No real worries about the input from the battery/charge system on this - the LT device is rated up to 40V on the input but some spike filtering from a series inductor and parallel capacitor ought to be used (or even a LDO linear voltage regulator set for 15V just to take away the "nasties").

Answer (score 1):

A small sealed lead-acid (SLA) battery might prove more economical than a huge capacitor.

(Photo from [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/BP1.2-12-T1/522-1007-ND/653328)).

[image]

The circuit could consist of a diode with a resistor (to charge the battery) across it. Something like 15 ohms 10W (ceramic resistor) would be conservative. Plus, you'd need a timer if you wanted the power to turn off after some seconds.